# Django - ListView - template for loop does not display any items

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

**well_list.html**

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    {% for item in well_info %}
    <th>item</th>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
</thead>
```

**project/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from eric_base import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('contextual/', include('eric_base.urls')),
    path('well_list/', views.well_list)
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View, TemplateView, ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView

from . import models

class WellInfoListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'well_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'well_info'
    model = models.WellInfo
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


# Create your models here.
class WellInfo(models.Model):
    api = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    region_location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    spud_date = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    well_bore = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    rig_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("")
```

Since I correctly defined `context_object_name = 'well_info'` in `views.py`, and I used `{% for item in well_info %}` in the html, I was expecting that I would get at least something from the model attributes. But when I run this code, I don't get anything. The header row just disappears like the following screenshot:

[image]

I want the table headers to have the attribute names defined in models.py, but apparently its not grabbing anything from it. Why is it not grabbing any attributes from `models.py`, and how can I display only the attribute names as a column header?

So I want the table headers to be:

```
Api | Name | Region Location | Spud Date | Well Bore | Rig Name | Status
```

without the values of each keys.

Comment: Can you post the full source for `well_list.html` (or at least all the relevant portions)? The snippet you posted does not have sufficient information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using the Model _meta API. In your views you can put the fields into a list like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View, TemplateView, ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView

from .models import WellInfo

class WellInfoListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'well_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'well_info'
    model = WellInfo

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(WellInfoListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['fields'] = [field.name for field in WellInfo._meta.get_fields()]
        return ctx
```

and then in your template you can have

```
<thead>
    {% for field in fields %}
    <th>{{ field }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
</thead>
```