# Why isn't Django passing ImageField data via ListView to a template?

Tags: django, django-views

This is my first programming project, and first question on StackOverflow - so please be gentle! I've been good and checked all the relevant existing questions and answers - apologies in advance if I've missed it.

I have a model that contains images:

**models.py**

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='portfolio-images/', blank=False, null=False)
    uploaded_by = get_user_model()
    uploaded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    alt_text = models.CharField(verbose_name='Alternate text', max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.alt_text

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('image_detail', args=[str(self.alt_text)])
```

Which is handled by these views:

**views.py**

```
class ImageDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Image
    context_object_name = 'image'
    template_name = 'image_detail.html'

class ImageListView(ListView):
    model = Image
    context_object_name = 'images'
    template_name = 'image_list.html'
```

Now when these are passed to their relevant templates, the DetailView works as it should - passes the url  to the template using this code, and the image renders in the browser.

**image_detail.html**

```
... 
<img src="{{ image.image.url }}" alt="{{ image.alt_text }}">
...
```

But the ListView does not pass the url or alt-text into the template. Here's the code I use to call it in the template:

**image_list.html**

```
{% for image in images %}
<img src="{{ images.image.url }}" alt="{{ images.alt_text }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Weirdly, it is getting a response from the database, as the loop creates 5  tags when it renders the page - and there are 5 images in the table. But it doesn't add the image url or alt text:

**127.0.0.1:8000/images/**

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
  <img src="" alt="">
</div>
```

Would really appreciate any suggestions - thanks a bunch.

Comment: Does this answer your quesiton? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412917/django-listview-template-for-loop-does-not-display-any-items

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MohitC, but unfortunately not.

Comment: images.image.url should be image.image.url.

Comment: Cheers @MattHardcastle! You've got it. And there was me thinking I'd checked thoroughly for typos in my code.